# chosen select javascript option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I use [Chosen](https://github.com/adunkman/chosen) select library.
I have question in select option.

Example select box

```
<select>
  <option>co.google</option>
  <option>co.yahoo</option>
  <option>co.lycos</option>
</select>
```

If I search "oole" return "co.google"
now recognize same first charactor.
Is it possible?
where to change?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your problem, you want to use Chosen but with a sort of typing errors tolerance?

Sorry but Chosen only works with exact typing.

You should have a look to autocomplete lib which use fuzzy search.

Here is the opened issue about implementing fuzzy search in Chosen: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/858

I suggest you to switch to this lib: http://fusejs.io/
It does fuzzy search and it's really easy to style.

Comment: i change code same your link but same before change

Comment: Have completed my answer with a lib suggestion. If it's solve your need, don't hesitate to mark as solved.